# Electric field energy contribution of proton to its inertia

Tags: particle-physics, atomic-physics, classical-electrodynamics

Quoting from the book ***Introduction to elementary particles*** by ***Griffiths***. Here ***two*** refers to **proton** and **neutron**.

> Heisenberg’ proposed
>   that we regard them as two “states” of a single particle, the nucleon. Even the
>   small difference in mass might be attributed to the fact that the proton is charged,
>   since the energy stored in its electric field contributes, according to Einstein’s
>   formula ($E = mc^2$) to its inertia. Unfortunately, this argument suggests that the
>   proton should be the heavier of the two, which is not only untrue, but would be
>   disastrous for the stability of matter.

How can I calculate how much proton's electric field contributes to its mass? My problem is that I read that self energy associated with a point charge is infinity so how can it contribute a finite mass? Is is that we take energy density rather than total energy? If we take energy density, why, shouldn't we be taking total energy?

Comment: Protons aren't point charges though.

Comment: So do you mean total electric field energy contribution is finite?

Comment: The energy in the electric field due to a charge distribution is finite unless the charge distribution itself becomes infinite at some points. I don't know what goes on inside a proton, but I would guess there isn't an infinite charge density at any interior point.

Comment: The quarks that make up the proton are charged and they are believed to be point particles.

Comment: are you looking for an exact answer or an estimate (i.e. some model calculation) of what this would be?

Comment: An estimate would be fine... As I told you the problem is that infinity thing.. Once i get away with that.. Everything's fine then.